# How to remove url from string in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove all URLs inside a string (replace them with "") I searched around but couldn't really find what I want.
Example:

```
final Sting a = 'aaaaaaaaaa=http://url.com/bla1/blah1/';
```

I want the result to be:

```
print(a);

output:aaaaaaaaaa=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the below regex to extract and remove all the URLs from a string:

```
final string = 'aaaaaaaaaa=http://url.com/bla1/blah1/';
final newString = string.replaceAll(RegExp(r"(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?"), "");
print(newString);
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: Edited, will you try now?

Comment: sameeeeee  :( :(

Comment: Edited with some workaround, please try again, and let me know

Comment: thank you but it's still the same

Comment: Can you please show me the input and output applied with the solution?

Comment: I copied your code to test it, output: aaaaaaaaaa=http://url.com/bla1/blah1/

Comment: Great, again change, will you please show the output now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233816/discussion-between-gourango-sutradhar-and-minh-nguyen).

Comment: Edited, have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info? :)

Can the string have +1 url?
Will the separator be always "="?

```
final String a = '"<p style="text-align: justify;">“<a title="abcd" href="stackoverflow.com/">abcd</a>” </p>"';
final noUrl = a.replaceRange(a.indexOf("<a")-1, a.indexOf("</a>")+5, "");
```

```
"<p style="text-align: justify;"> </p>"
```

it works if you only have 1  tag, otherwise we'll need to use regex :)

Comment: my string "<p style="text-align: justify;">“<a title="abcd" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">abcd</a>” </p>" :(

Comment: i want to remove <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
final Sting a = 'aaaaaaaaaa=http://url.com/bla1/blah1/';
String result = a.substring(0, a.indexOf('http'));
  
print(result);
```

result will have everything before http

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all anchor tags in a string with the following regular expression.

```
// Your string
final a = '<p style="text-align: justify;">“<a title="abcd" href="stackoverflow.com/">abcd</a>” </p>';
// Regex for anchor tags
final regex = RegExp(r"<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>");
// Remove all of them
final noUrls = a.replaceAll(regex, "");
// Print the result
print(noUrls);
```